# Local prometheus can't reach Spring Boot App running in IDE

Tags: docker, prometheus, spring-boot-actuator

I have a running Spring Boot application to which I added the actuator and micrometer-prometheus dependencies.

When using Postman, I can successfully reach the Prometheus endpoint `/actuator/prometheus`.

Prometheus is started with the docker-compose file I copied below.

The problem:
By using the UI, I see that the endpoint is not reachable by Prometheus.

[image]

The docker-compose.yml

```
prometheus:
image: prom/prometheus
container_name: prometheus
ports:
  - "9090:9090"
volumes:
  - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

The prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'backend'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 3s
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['127.0.0.1:8080']
        labels:
          application: 'app'
```

And the response when using Postman

[image]

Comment: You can't reach host machine where your Spring Boot application is deployed by using `127.0.0.1` (or `localhost`) from inside docker container. You need to use `host.docker.internal` instead - like this `targets: ['host.docker.internal:8080']`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko now I get the error :
`Get "http://host.docker.internal:8080/actuator/prometheus": dial tcp: lookup host.docker.internal on 127.0.0.11:53: no such host`

Do I need to define the network of the prometheus service inside the docker-compose.yml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring Boot application is running inside your IDE and is accessible by the local host. If we configure Prometheus to use the local host to communicate the spring boot application, it won't work because the Prometheus container has its own local host while it is running in Docker. It gives the error. You can do the following changes to your docker-compose.yml and prometheus.yml to prometheus access to PC ports

1.docker-compose.yml

```
 prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    container_name: prometheus
    ports:
      - "9090:9090"
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    extra_hosts:
      - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
```

2.prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'backend'
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    scrape_interval: 3s
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ 'host.docker.internal:8080']
        labels:
          application: 'app'
```